# Millions of MySQL Insert On Duplicate Key Update - very slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `research_words` which has some hundred million rows.

Every day I have tens of million of new rows to be added, about 5% of them are totally new rows, and 95% are updates which have to add to some columns in that row. I don't know which is which so I use:

```
INSERT INTO research_words
  (word1,word2,origyear,cat,numbooks,numpages,numwords)
VALUES
  (34272,268706,1914,1,1,1,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  numbooks=numbooks+1,numpages=numpages+1,numwords=numwords+1
```

This is an InnoDB table where the primary key is over `word1,word2,origyear,cat`.

The issue I'm having is that I have to insert the new rows each day and it's taking longer than 24 hours to insert each days rows! Obviously I can't have it taking longer than a day to insert the rows for the day. I have to find a way to make the inserts faster.

For other tables I've had great success with `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS;` and `LOAD DATA INFILE`, which allows me to add billions of rows in less than an hour. That would be great, except that unfortunately I am incrementing to columns in this table. I doubt disabling the keys would help either because surely it will need them to check whether the row exists in order to add it.

My scripts are in PHP but when I add the rows I do so by an `exec` call directly to MySQL and pass it a text file of commands, instead of sending them with PHP, since it's faster this way.

Any ideas to fix the speed issue here?

Comment: Sorry for offtop, but it is interesting how much do you gain from using direct exec commands? did you measure it?

Comment: MySQL just processes it all more efficiently when it comes as one giant query instead of millions of individual queries, especially with the keys disabled. The difference was minutes instead of hours.

Comment: That is what I understand, but you can send huge query using PDO or mysqli adapter, not via the interection with MySQL through exec command. What is the gain from this?

Comment: Yes of course you can, that would be about as fast, the performance gain I mentioned was assuming individual queries (which would be inefficient). In my case I'm importing files of several GB in size - to send it to MySQL via PHP is just not feasible. It makes more sense to save it all to a file and then import this file with MySQL more directly.

Comment: Don't think this counts as a full answer, but useful info. ALTER TABLE DISABLE KEYS only disables non-unique keys, so you could add that to your inserts if you have non-unique keys in addition to the unique ones used to check for the row's existence. However I doubt that it will have a sufficient effect to reduce your insert times below the 24-hour threshold.
Source: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but perhaps worth an answer all the same.
Part of the issue stems from the large number of inserts being run essentially one at a time, with a unique index update after each one.
In these instances, a better technique might be to select *n* rows to insert and put them in a temp table, left join them to the destination table, calculate their new values (in OP's situation IFNULL(dest.numpages+1,1) etc.) and then run two further commands - an insert where the insert fields are 1 and an update where they're greater. The updates don't require an index refresh, so they run much faster; the inserts don't require the same ON DUPLICATE KEY logic.